# Ubuntu VMware (Windows Host) - Apache only routeable by LocalHost

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, networking, linux-networking, vmware-workstation

I am a Windows based, python developer, who is currently working with configuring his first linux VM.

I am able to get the VM set up, with internet access. I can apt-get with no issues.

After installing Apache on the VM, I can test it by accessing localhost [image]

However, I cannot access this via a Browser on the **host**.

I can SSH to the VM just fine, I can ping it, I can Telnet on port 80.

I would like to access it through it's IP Address. (192.168.21.128) From both the Host, and the VM (and other networked devices).

I am behind a corporate firewall, but all routing is internal, I just need it to be accessible from my host.

Thanks for reading, Ive found a bunch of information online, but nothing has been able to help yet.

---

Things I tried.

### Apache2.conf

Tried setting
ServerName 0.0.0.0:80

Checked all my  IP Tables (looks good but Im no expert[image])

Answer (score 1):

**ServerName** is not the directive you want to set. 
**Listen** should be on all interfaces and maybe test specific with:

`(Listen 192.168.21.128:80)`

as well as you want:

`<VirtualHost *:80>`

VM's IP is 192.168.21.128 - is it from the host-bridge-adapter or corporate-dhcp?
Anyway if you can *successfully*

```
telnet 192.168.21.128 80
```

your browser will do too. What's the actual error message in the browser?

Comment: Hi @roothahn, thanks for the response. I am very new to apache configs so please excuse my ignorance but should Listen be configed in apache.conf or httpd.conf?..... The actual error message in the browser is simply "Gateway Timeout - Server is unreachable at this moment".... I  have the network adapter configured in NAT mode, and i believe the IP is generated via DHCP but am not sure how to check

Comment: If the 192-IP is provided via corporate-dhcp, and it is not neccessary to serve the apache for other users on the network, you could try to add a host-only adapter to your vm. But actually the routing should be intelligent enough to route directly to the vm and not via gateway. tracert from windows to the vm-192-IP?

Comment: tracert gives back 1 hop in <1ms